# Add lineChart to Pdf file using Afreechart and itextg

Tags: android, itextg

I am trying to add a Line Chart to Pdf file in android using itext and AFreeChart. I have done this in java using itextpdf and JFreeChart. But i am stuck at the part where graph is added to pdf. Please help.

I don't know how to bind the canvas to PdfTemplate, or is there a different way of doing this, any suggestions are appreciated.

This is my android code

```
AFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("R","Unit1","unit2",dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL,true,false,false);
PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();

PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(100,200);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
RectShape rectShape = new RectShape(0,0,100,200);
chart.draw(canvas,rectShape);
cb.addTemplate(tp,280,35);
```

This is my Java code

```
PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
Graphics2D g2d = tp.createGraphics(width, height, new DefaultFontMapper());
Rectangle2D r2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
chart.draw(g2d, r2d);
```

The graph is not being plotted in the pdf at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question using Bitmap.

The code is as follows

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
RectShape rectShape = new RectShape(0,0,width,height);
chart.draw(canvas,rectShape);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream3);
Image temp = Image.getInstance(stream3.toByteArray());
temp.setAbsolutePosition(0,0);
tp.addImage(temp);
cb.addTemplate(tp,0,100);
```